# pgAdmin connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'd like to run a postgre db server on localhost:5432. It used to work, then I updated to mac os 13.2. Now if I enter my password to connect to local postgre server, the following error being shown:
[image: pgAdmin error message]
Anybody knows how to solve this issue?

I tried to start the postgre sql local server.

Comment: Did you start the database server? And did you check the logfiles from the database server to get the confirmation that it successfully started?

Comment: Log in the database server's log file for a description of why the password authentication failed.